# Is there a simple way to pass data into an MVC3 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

[Edit] To try to clarify:

I have a view that needs to be launched from an external application.  The application requires string data to be passed from an external application (the data is free text and too long to pass as a query parameter),  So I would like to launch the MVC application with a POST request.  The view that is launched also needs to post data back to itself in order to submit the data it collects for storage in a database.  So I end up with a View with two HttpPost flagged methods in my controller (MVC throws an error that there are ambiguous Create methods).

So in the code below Create() would be posted to from the external application.  Create(FormCollection collection) would be posted to when a displayed View is submitted.

```
//POST:  /Application/Create   
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
     MyModel model = new MyModel();     
     //Parse External Data to model from Request.InputStream
     return View(Model); 
}

//POST: /Application/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
      //Save form collection data to database
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So long story short, how can I post data to an MVC application to launch a view, without getting an error for an ambiguous call.

Thanks.

Comment: this is a bit hard to follow especially the portion about having to name the controllers separately. can you revise with a bit more detail? why are you using the request object rather than parameters in an action method or FormsCollection. You can change the view you are going to by return View("xyz") if that matters here but I cant tell the real scenario : )

Comment: What do you want to do with the "view". Is this something the user needs to see, is the result parsed in an application, saved to disk, ...

Comment: The user needs to see it, supply some information, then that information and a portion of the passed in data will be saved to a database.

Comment: Is the view started from another web-based application, or from a windows.forms like application? What I mean is, do you need to start the browser to perform a post, or is there already a browser active?

Comment: It is launched from another web app so a browser is already active.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case when the post method comes in from the outside:

```
return View("ConfirmCreate", model)
```

Then create an action method named ConfirmCreate. After ConfirmCreate is called the second time you will redirect back to Index as you have.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do this by changing the POST call to load the application to a PUT To avoid have duplicate post endpoints), then sending the PUT from an ajax call in another application and replacing the current document with the returned html from the successful ajax call.  Thanks for the suggestions.